# insert checkbox values into database within a separate column of the query separated by commas

Tags: php

I need help for this problem that I've been trying to solve for a while (I'm new in PHP). I have a form with several checkboxes whose values are pulled from a specific table of the database. I managed to display them in the form,  but cannot insert their values into the table connected to that specific page since there is ony one column.I want to enter all the selected values of the checkbox into that single column separated by commas.

Here's the code:

```
url <BR><?php $query  = "SELECT url FROM webmeasurements";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{     $url  = $row[0];    
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"url\" value=\"$row[0]\" />$row[0]<br />";
$checkbox_values = implode(';', $_POST['url']);   }  
?> 

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> 
</form> 
<?php

if(isset($_POST['url']))
{  echo $url;
 foreach ($_POST['url'] as $statename)
 {
   $url=implode(',',$statename)
  }
}
$q="insert into table (url) values ($url)";
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [inserting checkbox such that all the selected values get displayed in the databse in a single colukn separated by commas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037731/inserting-checkbox-such-that-all-the-selected-values-get-displayed-in-the-databse)

Comment: I don't see any checkboxes in this code snippet, only radio buttons

Comment: @Rahima looking at your question history, your writing style is good, but I think you need to change your approach a bit if you want good answers - try to work out a more isolated version of the problem you're having. Show more detail and where you're stuck

Comment: oh!sorry. i have edited it now

Comment: I have problem with the "if(isset($_POST['url'])) " part which is not getting executed.can u please find th errors..                    My requirement is to enter all the selected checkbox values to a single column of the query in a database separated by commas

Answer (score 0):

You should give each checkbox a different name, not name="url" for all, and then check if(isset($_POST['checkbox_name'])).